# How to create checkbox in select options list using only html?

Tags: html, checkbox, html-select

I want to create a checkbox for  each option of select list..

I want checkbox beside each option using only HTML.

Comment: This is easily Googled.

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-List-with-Checkboxes-MultiSelect check this out

Answer (score 0):

Try tHis, the best I can do. Use Bootstrap Multiselect,

```js
$(function() {

$('#chkveg').multiselect({

includeSelectAllOption: true

});

$('#btnget').click(function() {

alert($('#chkveg').val());

})

});
```

```css
.multiselect-container>li>a>label {
  padding: 4px 20px 3px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="form1">

<div style="padding:20px">

<select id="chkveg" multiple="multiple">

<option value="cheese">Cheese</option>

<option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>

<option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>

<option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>

<option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>

<option value="onions">Onions</option>

</select><br /><br />

<input type="button" id="btnget" value="Get Selected Values" />

</div>

</form>
```